# Windows 7 Task Scheduler Run On Idle End

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler

I want to run a task every time I sit down at my computer, so that I will effectively run the task once when the computer ceases to be idle.  I can't see a way to do this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: May we know the task you wish to run?  Have you much experience of Task Scheduler?

Comment: So you want a task to run automatically as soon as you start using the PC? Is it too hard to, for example, manually click a shortcut? Otherwise as Guy said, configure Group Policy settings and use Task Scheduler as mentioned [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/240227-task-scheduler-trigger-screensaver-event-possible.html) to trigger the task based on event IDs for specific criteria, such as logon/logoff, workstation lock/unlock, screensaver start/end etc.

Comment: It is not critical, but I want to log the time spent actually sitting at the pc.  I have a little Autohotkey program that I wrote that will do some things in the background for me.  I could click a shortcut, but I don't trust myself to.  I could also create an event to happen at login, but I prefer not to sign in and out on this pc.  There are other ways, but as far as I can tell, this is the optimal solution for what I am looking to do.   I will check the link.

Comment: I was unaware of screensaver end event.  That may do it.